# Create an aspect in Alfresco Content Model

Tags: database-design, content-management-system, database-schema, alfresco, content-model

I am starting currently using Alfresco CMS. I need to create an "aspect" in my content model which must contains a number of properties as:

```
Aspect: 
    property 1 : String
    property 2 : int
    property 3 : int
    property 4 : long
```

Moreover it must contains two more properties which are composed either of number of properties as:

```
Format: 
   FormatProperty1: int
   FormatProperty2: int
   FormatProperty3: int

Metadata:
   list1: List<String>
   list2: List<String>
   MetadataProperty 3: boolean
```

I have not yet created neither a simple content model nor an aspect in Alfresco. Based on my previous knowledge in Relational Databases I perceive the above structure as association between tables. How can I carry out that in Alfresco content model with an aspect or more?

Comment: Alfresco doesn't use a relational model, you want to think something a bit more like how the likes of LDAP work (if you know that). Have you tried reading some tutorials already?

Comment: Yes I have just read http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Step_by_Step_Model_Definition . It is helpful to some point but without having dealt with Alfresco till now I cannot proceed with certainty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look [here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Step-By-Step%3a_Creating_A_Custom_Model) first.
Creating a model in Alfresco is far away from a DB.

it's just an XML well defined. You have to write the XML first, then initialize it through bootstrap.

Example XML Model cmodModel.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Definition of new Model -->
<model name="custom:custommodel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">
    <!-- Optional meta-data about the model -->
    <description>Custom Model</description>
    <author>Whatever</author>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <!-- Imports are required to allow references to definitions in other models -->
    <imports>
        <!-- Import Alfresco Dictionary Definitions -->
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d" />
        <!-- Import Alfresco Content Domain Model Definitions -->
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm" />
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0" prefix="sys" />
    </imports>
    <!-- Introduction of new namespaces defined by this model -->
    <namespaces>
        <namespace uri="custom.model" prefix="cmod" />
    </namespaces>
    <!-- Lists <String> -->
    <constraints>
        <constraint name="cmod:liststring1" type="LIST">
            <parameter name="allowedValues">
                <list>
                    <value>value 1</value>
                    <value>value 2</value>
                </list>
            </parameter>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="cmod:liststring2" type="LIST">
            <parameter name="allowedValues">
                <list>
                    <value>value 1</value>
                    <value>value 2</value>
                </list>
            </parameter>
        </constraint>
    </constraints> 
    <types>
        <!-- Document Type -->
        <type name="cmod:customDoc">
            <title>Document</title>
            <description>Document</description>
            <parent>cm:content</parent>
            <mandatory-aspects>
                <aspect>cmod:aspectBase</aspect>
                <aspect>cmod:aspectFormat</aspect>
                <aspect>cmod:aspectMetadata</aspect>
            </mandatory-aspects>
        </type>
</types> 
    <!-- Definition of custom aspects  -->
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="cmod:aspectBase">
            <title>Aspect base properties</title>
            <properties>
                <property name="cmod:property1">
                    <title>p1</title>
                    <description>p1</description>
                    <type>d:text</type>
                </property>
                <property name="cmod:property2">
                    <title>p2</title>
                    <description>p2</description>
                    <type>d:int</type>
                </property>
                <property name="cmod:property3">
                    <title>p3</title>
                    <description>p3</description>
                    <type>d:int</type>
                </property>
                <property name="cmod:property4">
                    <title>p4</title>
                    <description>p4</description>
                    <type>d:text</type>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </aspect>
        <aspect name="cmod:aspectFormat">
            <title>Aspect Format</title>
            <properties>
                <property name="cmod:formatProperty1">
                    <title>fp1</title>
                    <description>fp1</description>
                    <type>d:int</type>
                </property>
                <property name="cmod:formatProperty2">
                    <title>fp2</title>
                    <description>fp2</description>
                    <type>d:int</type>
                </property>
                <property name="cmod:formatProperty3">
                    <title>fp3</title>
                    <description>fp3</description>
                    <type>d:int</type>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </aspect>
        <aspect name="cmod:aspectMetadata">
            <title>Aspetto Metadata</title>
            <properties>
                <property name="cmod:metadataProperty1">
                    <title>mp1</title>
                    <description>mp1</description>
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint ref="cmod:liststring1" />
                    </constraints>
                </property>
                <property name="cmod:metadataProperty2">
                    <title>mp2</title>
                    <description>mp2</description>
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint ref="cmod:liststring2" />
                    </constraints>
                </property>
                <property name="cmod:metadataProperty3">
                    <title>mp3</title>
                    <description>mp3</description>
                    <type>d:boolean</type>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </aspect>
</aspects>
</model>
```

model context named cmod-model-context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>

<beans>
    <!-- Registration of new models -->
    <bean id="extension.dictionaryBootstrap" 
        parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" 
        depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
        <property name="models">
            <list>
                <value>alfresco/extension/model/cmodModel.xml</value>
          </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It seems a good approach. Although I have read the most common Tutorials and examples residing in web sites, I still cannot comprehend this story with "constraints" and "lists". I see you also use it and you specify for each list two values. What 's the meaning of these values, as long as the list can accept an arbitrary number of values?

Comment: Sorry , what do you mean by "initialize it through bootstrap", currently I had to restart tomcat to get aspect to work. Is there any other way to get those aspects.. It would be great if it works without tomcat restart..Thanks.

Comment: By bootstrap is meant by deploying the xml and restarting tomcat. You can use the dynamic approach described here http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/deploy-dynamic.html Basically it means you deploy the xml inside the Company Home/Data Dictionary/Models, update the content properties with Model Active set to true. That way no restart is necessary. Care because this is not the recon'd way to update the content model in Alfresco.

Answer (score 7):

Let me try to add some extra info to @Alch3mi5t's answer based on your comment. I'm using an imaginary business case here.

Basically, Alfresco model consists of 3 sections: constraints, types and aspects. Plus, I'll add associations in the mix.

- **Type**

Each node in alfresco (you might incorrectly think of it as of a "record") has a type. So this type has properties ("columns"). So you have your base type, let's say it's called **Vendor**. It has two props, Name and tax ID (string and int).
Your type definition would look like:

```
<type name="myCompany:vendor">
  <title>Vendor</type>
  <parent>cm:folder</parent>
  <properties>
    <property name="myCompany:vendorName">
      <title>Vendor name</title>
      <type>d:text</type>
    </property>
    <property name="myCompany:vendorTaxID">
      <title>Vendor Tax ID</title>
      <type>d:int</type>
    </property>
  </properties>
</type>
```

There goes your type, not unlike a db table with columns vendorName and vendorTaxID of the string and int type.

- **Constraint**

Let's say you now have to add some constraint on the tax id - simple regex example.
So you have a constraint defined like this:

```
<constraint name="myCompany:taxIdConstraint" type="REGEX">
  <parameter name="expression">
    <value>^ID[1-9](\-[1-9])*</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="requiresMatch">
    <value>true</value>
  </parameter>
</constraint>
```

Now we only need to modify our taxId property:

```
<property name="myCompany:vendorTaxID">
  <title>Vendor Tax ID</title>
  <type>d:int</type>
  <constraints>
    <constraint ref="myCompany:taxIdConstraint">
  </constraints>
</property>
```

So, you now placed a constraint on that property.

- **Aspect**
  Now you want an aspect - in Alfresco, this would be as if you want to add few extra columns to that table.

No - better analogy, you want a relation from your original table. So if it's null, it's null. But alternatively, it creates a 1-1 (usually) relation to your records to that other table.

The baseline here is that you would never add anything into the aspect table alone - it only comes as an addition to the base type. An example aspect:

```
<aspect name="myCompany:myAspect">
  <title>Address aspect</title>
  <properties>
    <property name="myCompany:city">
      <title>City</title>
      <type>d:text</type>
    </property>
  </properties>
</aspect>
```

You can make this a mandatory aspect if you add this to your type definition (just after the *properties* section):

```
<mandatory-aspects>
  <aspect>myCompany:myAspect</aspect>
</mandatory-aspects>
```

Now, you can add a "record" to your base "table", and if you added this as a mandatory aspect, then each record will have 3 props: name, tax id and city. If not mandatory, then each record will have two base columns, but you will be able to add the third to select few. Programatically or manually, doesn't matter.

- **Associations**
  Now we can also add associatons in the mix: this is a link only between two nodes (or "records").
  So, after the *properties* section in your type, you can add *associations* section. Let's say you want to connect (some) Vendors to their creators (Key accounts).

You add this to your type:

```
<associations>
  <association name="myCompany:keyAccountManager">
    <source>
      <mandatory>false</mandatory>
      <many>true</many>
    </source>
    <target>
      <class>cm:person</class>
      <mandatory>false</mandatory>
      <many>true</many>
    </target>
  </association>
</associations>
```

There you have it! You can now connect some or all of the Vendors in your Vendor table to their respective KAMs (so you can email KAMs when something is going on with the Vendor, let's say). Basically, a 1-n connection between your Vendors table and your Users table.
1-n meaning you can connect one Vendor to many Persons. You can also connect different Vendors to one person. (the many parameters).

You can also add association to an aspect, in the same manner:

```
<aspect name="myCompany:stateAspect">
 <properties>
 ...
 </properties>
 <associations>
  <association name="myCompany:myState">
    <source>
      <mandatory>true</mandatory>
      <many>true</many>
    </source>
    <target>
      <class>cm:folder</class>
      <mandatory>false</mandatory>
      <many>true</many>
    </target>
  </association>
 </associations>
</aspect>
```

Now you can create regular alfresco folders (cm:folder type) and name them after the state, and have each of the cities be connected to one of them folders. (Not the best way, but shows my point.)
so this association is mandatory, meaning if you add this other aspect (not the original one), which is not mandatory, you HAVE to create an association.

So play with the combinations to do what you need.

- **Model**

So now you have your example model:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <model name="myCompany:myContentModel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">
      <description>Custom Content Model</description>
      <author>Zlatko Đurić</author>
      <published>2013-03-22</published>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <imports>
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
      </imports>

      <namespaces>
        <namespace uri="myCompany.model" prefix="bv"/>
      </namespaces>

      <constraints>
        <constraint name="myCompany:taxIdConstraint" type="REGEX">
          <parameter name="expression">
            <value>^ID[1-9](\-[1-9])*</value>
          </parameter>
          <parameter name="requiresMatch">
            <value>true</value>
          </parameter>
        </constraint>
      </constraints>

      <types>
        <type name="myCompany:vendor">
          <title>Vendor</type>
          <parent>cm:folder</parent>
          <properties>
            <property name="myCompany:vendorName">
              <title>Vendor name</title>
              <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="myCompany:vendorTaxID">
              <title>Vendor Tax ID</title>
              <type>d:int</type>
              <constraints>
                <constraint ref="myCompany:taxIdConstraint">
              </constraints>
              </property>
          </properties>
          <mandatory-aspects>
            <aspect>myCompany:myAspect</aspect>
          </mandatory-aspects>
          <associations>
            <association name="myCompany:keyAccountManager">
              <source>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                <many>true</many>
              </source>
              <target>
                <class>cm:person</class>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                <many>true</many>
              </target>
            </association>
          </associations>
        </type>
      </types>

      <aspects>
        <aspect name="myCompany:myAspect">
          <title>Address aspect</title>
          <properties>
            <property name="myCompany:city">
              <title>City</title>
              <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
          </properties>

          <associations>
            <association name="myCompany:myState">
              <source>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                <many>true</many>
              </source>
              <target>
                <class>cm:folder</class>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                <many>true</many>
              </target>
            </association>
           </associations>
         </aspect>
      </aspects>
    </model>

There, I hope this helps you.
```

Comment: I infer from your answer that associations is not what I need to tackle my case. Could I define though an Aspect (not a type) which contains other aspects? Just as @Alch3mi5t approach with the difference that the outer "element" should be an aspect? If it is not possible, could I define an aspect with associations to types? However the outer element should still be an aspect.

Comment: Yes, you can add your association in an aspect too, it should work, let me edit post :)